# Using Pandora in Firefox without Flash possible?

Tags: firefox, pandora

I recently installed the great FlashHider addon for Firefox which blocks Flash for sites that don't really need it.

Now I tried to listen to Pandora but it says

> Please ensure you are using the latest Flash Player.
>
> If you are unable or do not wish to upgrade your Flash Player,
>   please try a different browser.

Or, in another instance

> In order to use Pandora internet radio, please upgrade to a more current browser or install a newer version of Flash (v.10 or later).

My browser also appears to meet [their requirements](https://help.pandora.com/customer/en/portal/articles/166391-minimum-specifications-to-run-pandora#2) (just says "Latest Version of Firefox" with auto-updating enabled which I have), so I am out of ideas why it doesn't work.